# Shutdown and Reboot is causing Logout

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 11.10 logs off when clicking shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90118/ubuntu-11-10-logs-off-when-clicking-shutdown)

While I am trying to Reboot or Shutdown my system using the menu, I am again routed to Login page. From the login page I am able to shutdown or reboot the system. I have tried the command line and it is working fine. I have install the latest ATI drivers ( 9.10)  manually in my system.

[image]

Please help me to resolv this issue.

Comment: ... or this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103800/shutdown-or-restart-only-logs-me-out