# Ubuntu 11.10 logs off when clicking shutdown

Tags: shutdown, logout

As the title says: when I click Shutdown from the menu it logs off. When I click shutdown from the log-in menu it does nothing. I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10. I can force it to shutdown by the command below, but I don't want to keep typing that whenever I want to shutdown my laptop.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

So it's probably processes which arn't closing. I'm a novice linux user, so I have no idea how to rule out the software causing this. I think it's either Gwibber/Empathy, perhaps Mozilla Thunderbird, because this is happening since I started using this.

So a few questions:

1. How do I rule out what software is causing this?
2. How do I stop it from not closing on shutdown?
3. If 1. and 2. don't work is it possible to add top command to the shutdown process?

Edit: Rourke here. Somehow I cannot accept the below comment from mech-e as the solution. Thank you this was indeed the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your account set to autologin and is your home folder encrypted? Had same problem and fixed it by turning 'autologin' for user off. Need to do `sudo reboot` or `shutdown -h now` from terminal, then either use GUI via User Account settings and turn off autologin or follow these steps from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792 :

> raggar (mbaart) wrote on 2011-11-04: #24
>
> I found a possible solution to this bug. It has something to do with the auto login >function in the user management from Unity. When activated it cannot shutdown anymore. >Also disable the auto login is not possible anymore.
>
> What I did:
> `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
>
> remove the line:
> `autologin-user= YOUR USERNAME`
>
> Restart your computer with:
> `sudo shutdown -h now`
>
> After that I had a system that worked normally again.

Comment: this solution did not solve my problem.

Comment: @ultrajohn Since it did solve the OP's problem and didn't solve yours, your probably probably differs from the OP's in some important (but possibly subtle) way. I recommend posting a new question about your problem. You can include a link to this question in your new question.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and tracked it down to having another account/profile logged in at the same time.

Logged into Account A
Switched to Account B (testing a new user)
Forgot about A, User B couldn't shutdown and would drop back to the login screen.

Fix : Logout of Account A, B can now shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and found a solution here:

http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2012/01/how-to-shut-down-ubuntu-11-10-computer/

It was a simple fix and worked for me!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and discovered it was from having a running shutdown command waiting for a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when I updated ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04. So, for this I searched online and found many things but not real answer. But by now I know that there is an app named **Plank** does not let that shutdown happen. So, we have 3 option,

**1.** We can remove it and replace it with **Docky** .

**2.** We can modify its startup and shutdown scrips.

**3.** Or just close it manually and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to shutdown is to use :

```
shutdown -H -P +2
```

because it leaves time for your processes to stop correctly.