# Why does "shutdown" option only log me out?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 11.10 logs off when clicking shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90118/ubuntu-11-10-logs-off-when-clicking-shutdown)

When I need to reboot (sadly, the days of 300+ days of uptime appear to be long gone) while logged into my account, the Shut Down option only logs me out - it does not shutdown the system.

When at the login screen, selecting the shutdown or restart option does nothing - I get a dialog box, but regardless of which option I select, nothing happens.

Interestingly enough, when I first boot up, selecting shutdown from the login screen works, as long as I haven't logged in yet.

Is this a known problem?  Any way to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: In the user accounts section of systems settings are you listed as an Administrator?

Comment: @Allan:  Yes, I'm listed as Administrator.  I should probably mention that this started happening after upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10.  Even if I ctrl-alt-f1 to get a shell, log in and "sudo shutdown now" it hangs.

Comment: I've had a similar issue since either 11.04 or 11.10, although I can "sudo shutdown -R now" with no problems.  (FWIW, I'm an Administrator as well.)