# Shutdown or Restart only logs me out

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, restart, logout

My workstation at work is running 11.10 (lightdm). Shutting down or restarting has always worked up till last week.

My workstation is generally left on through the week and shutdown at weekends.

When I click either Restart or Shutdown, it just logs me out.

Is there any logs I can see that will point to errors?

What might cause this? I haven't got auto login checked ([as one answer suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90118/ubuntu-11-10-logs-off-when-clicking-shutdown)).

`sudo halt` and `sudo reboot` both work... so why doesn't the UI buttons?

Comment: Could you link to the answer you're referring to?

Comment: You can try `sudo halt` from the terminal and see if that works

Comment: @BoltClock added as requested

Comment: @Hippo `sudo halt` and `sudo reboot` both work... so why doesn't the UI buttons?

Comment: I have the same problem. I saw somewhere else that rabbitmq might be causing it for some reason-- do you have rabbitmq installed?

Comment: I just removed rabbitmq from my machine and the problem went away.

Comment: No I don't have RabbitMQ installed, not unless it comes installed automatically!

Comment: Is dbus running?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because you have another session open (someone else logged in) Before you attempt shut down again, click on the user applet and see that no one else is logged in. If they are Shutdown and restart will only log you out.

Comment: I don't have any other user accounts on this machine, so this didn't help. Thanks!