# Logout when pressing on "shutdown" [Ubuntu 11.10]

Tags: logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown or Restart only logs me out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103800/shutdown-or-restart-only-logs-me-out)

when I click Shutdown from the menu it logs off. When I click shutdown from the log-in menu it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because you have another session open (someone else logged in) Before you attempt shut down again, click on the user applet and see that no one else is logged in. If they are Shutdown and restart will only log you out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at the login menu Shutdown will not work because you need Super User permissions in order to do that and since your not logged in the option doesnt work.

Comment: but when im logged in. if click Shutdown  from the menu it logs off.

Comment: Are you logged in anywhere else?  From a terminal?  If more than one user is logged into the system Shutdown and Restart will not work it will only log you out of the current session.  Try typing the command who from the command line and see what it says.  If there is more than one line returned then there is multiple logins on the system